# UITabBar's navigationbar hides navigationbar when view is presented modally

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have app with UItabBarTemplate with navigation controller.
On selecting tab bar ViewControllerA is shown which on button touch pushes UIPieChartTabController which inherits "UIViewController".
Now I want another tab bar in UIPieChartTabController.
so in viewDidLoad of UIPieChartTabController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

     UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
     contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
     self.view = contentView;
     [contentView release];
      UITabBarController *tabbar= [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
     tabbar.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
    piechartViewController *pr=[[piechartViewController alloc]init];
    pr.tagInAction=1;
    pr.title=@"Type";
    pr.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"trend.png"];
    pr.sDate=sDate;
    pr.nDate=nDate;

    piechartViewController *pr1=[[piechartViewController alloc]init];
    pr1.title=@"category";
    pr1.tagInAction=4;
    pr1.sDate=sDate;
    pr1.nDate=nDate;

    piechartViewController *pr2=[[piechartViewController alloc]init];
    pr2.title=@"paidWith";
    pr2.tagInAction=3;
    pr2.sDate=sDate;
    pr2.nDate=nDate;

    //tabbar.tabBar.delegate=self;
//this gave me error

    ExportRep *pr3=[[ExportRep alloc]init];
    pr3.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"database.png"];
    pr3.title=@"Export Expenses";

    [tabbar setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:pr,pr1,pr2,pr3,nil]];
    [self.view addSubview:tabbar.view];
    [pr release];
    [pr1 release];
    [pr2 release];
}
```

This piece of code worked but now when I select tab of viewController ExportRep type I tried

```
[self presentModalViewController:objMFMailComposeViewController animated:YES];
```

but navigationController of objMFMailComposeViewController hides behind navigationController of view that is presenting objMFMailComposeViewController.

Also viewWillAppear viewDidAppear of all the view controller which are bound to tab bar never gets called.

But none of this problem occurs for tabbar and viewcontroller which gets created by UITabbarTemplate.
Why Is it so? Whats wrong when I create Tab bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why new view which is being presented modally got its navigation bar hidden lies in  `[self.view addSubview:tabbar.view];`
so it got room to present its view only in parent controllers view thus got cut its navigation bar.
so to hack it I kept tab selected and instead of presenting it in selected view controller,have presented it in  main view controller only.

Answer (score 0):

placing another tabBar within a tabbarVC, is not recommended. Why not use a UIToolBar to do the swapping of Views in your PieChartVC instead?

-apart from that, the reason your code doesn't call viewWillAppear,viewDidAppear is because of this:

```
[tabbar setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:pr,pr1,pr2,pr3,nil]];
[self.view addSubview:tabbar.view];
```

here only loadView of those prs will be called.

the viewControllers you assign to the tabBars should instead be wrapped around UINavigationControllers.

So something like this instead would do the trick

```
UINavigationController *nc1 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:pr];
[nc1.view setFrame:CGRectMake:("the frame in which you wnt prs to be displayed")];
[pr.view setFrame:nc1.view.frame];
. // similarly assign NavControllers for all prs
.
.
.
[tabbar setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:nc,nc1,nc2,nc3,nil]];
    [self.view addSubview:tabbar.view];
```

Comment: okyeee so viewWillAppear will be called only if view is presented modally or pushed on navigation stack. ....hnmm...I have already tried creating navigation controller for every viewcontroller but it luks shabby if keep visible both navigationbar and if original hidden then i will loose track of original navigationbar :(

Comment: whts the reason for navigationbar of view presented modally hides behind original nav bar? If I present modally so it overlays only view of parentViewController???

Comment: 1) yes,it will look shabby, thats why two tabbarViewControllers are not adviced. so instead make a custom toolBar placed within your pieChartViewController. and use it to swap views.      2) the navigationpart i dont know dude; can you try [self.navigationController presentModal...]; this shouldn't work but just a try. :)